# Why Django's related_model property is returning string instead of Model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-jet

I have some strange behaviour, at least for me, that is causing me some bugs in my project.

I am using Django 1.9 and a third party django package ([django-jet](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/blob/master/jet/filters.py#L16)) that makes usage of `field.related_model` property in Django admin and sometimes it fails because it expects `field.related_model` returns a model instance and for some of my models is returning the model name.

[This is the property defined in Django code:](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L109)

```
@cached_property
def related_model(self):
    # Can't cache this property until all the models are loaded.
    apps.check_models_ready()
    return self.remote_field.model
```

Things that I tried:

- If Django's related_model is a *@property* instead a *@cached_property* it works and returns the model instance.
- If I call `field.remote_field.model` instead of `field.related_model` in the line that is causing the bug it works and returns the model instance.

Please, do you have any idea? I can make the workaround but I would like to know why this behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here arises because jet is trying to use `related_model` in the `RelatedFieldAjaxListFilter.field_choices()` method, and this may executed before all apps have been loaded.  If I understand correctly, the `related_model` value is initially a string, which is replaced with a model object in the course of model initialization.  If you try to get that value before the apps have all loaded, you may get either a string or an object, depending on the order in which the models are loaded.  And, since it's a cached property, getting a string value at that stage would cause the string value to be cached.  See, for example, the comment in `django.db.models.options`,

```
# The mechanism for getting at the related model is slightly odd -
# ideally, we'd just ask for field.related_model. However, related_model
# is a cached property, and all the models haven't been loaded yet, so
# we need to make sure we don't cache a string reference.
```

By making `related_name` an uncached property, you avoid that issue.

In the `django.contrib.admin.filters.RelatedFieldListFilter` code, they do NOT use `related_model` to get the model object, but instead use a utility function, `django.contrib.admin.utils.get_model_from_relation()`.      The `RelatedFieldAjaxListFilter.field_choices()` should probably be doing something similar.